# Getting image for product in Cart Screen

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, image, ecommerce

Really struggling with this (perhaps my brain is tired), but how would I get the image of a product for each entry in the cart screen in Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually depends where the image is stored - if the asset (image) field is on the product, and is called `myImage`, then as per Brad's example you'd use:

`lineitem.purchasable.product.myImage`

...BUT if it's in rather a field on the variant you would instead reference it as:

`lineitem.purchasable.myImage`

(This is because lineitem refers to a variant....in the case of a product without variants it references the implicitly created `defaultVariant`).

Comment: Somehow I knew either you or Luke would correct me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd access the product images just like you would any other [Assets field](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#examples) in Craft.

Assuming you've already got the cart, and your Assets field is called `productImages`, something like this should work:

```
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    <p>SKU: {{ item.sku }}</p>

    <ul>
    {% for image in item.purchasable.product.productImages %}
        <li><img src="{{ image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that but I get the following error.

Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "productImage".

I had assumed it would be as simple as fetching a normal asset, but everything I have tried fails.

Comment: That's why I said "and your Assets field is called `productImages`". :)  What's the name of the Assets field you're storing the product images in?

Comment: productImage. I have changed the code to reflect my asset field name.

Comment: When I do a dump. {{ dump(item) }} I can't even see any reference to the productImage field. :-(

Comment: Updated my answer.  And actually tested it this time. :)

Comment: That's the one Brad! item.purchasable.product - Thanks. Got me there in the end. :-) Good stuff.